# Android done button action onclick

Tags: android

I am working on android. In my login page I have a submit button and it is working fine. Now I need to make the android keyboard "Done" button action to have the same functionality of the submit button. How can I do this? Any help will be thankful in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement `OnEditorActionListener` for Editext. like

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //TODO: do something
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found

```
class DoneOnEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;    
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

source:

http://savagelook.com/blog/android/android-quick-tip-edittext-with-done-button-that-closes-the-keyboard

You should have done more googling

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `OnEditorActionListener`

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

        edit.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                    Log.i("check","Enter pressed");
                }    
                return false;
            }
        });
```